# How to sync a Samsung Galaxy Pro  with Banshee?

Tags: banshee, sync, samsung

I have a Samsung Galaxy Pro with Android Froyo which has 8GB worth of songs and I want to sync those with banshee on my home desktop which runs Ubuntu Natty 64 bit. There are videos on Youtube which show HTC syncing with Banshee, but when I connect my Samsung Galaxy Pro to my Ubuntu desktop using a USB cable, it does not show up.

Any help?

Comment: did those videos have any instructions given in their descriptions for how they set up sync?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a Samsung Galaxy Pro, but I do have a Captivate which is a Samsung Galaxy S model. The Galaxy Pro is a Galaxy S II model, but there's a good chance that they interact with Ubuntu in a similar way.

In order to get syncing with Banshee to work, I needed to turn on "USB Debugging" for my phone. To do so, go to `Settings > Applications > Development`

[image: Enable USB Debugging]

Now you can connect your phone to your computer. This will add a notification on your phone. Press the "USB Connected" notification.

[image: USB Connected]

This will bring up a new screen. Press "Connect to USB storage."

[image: Connect to USB storage]

Ubuntu should now prompt you to open the phone in Banshee.

[image: Prompt]

You should now be able to sync music from Banshee to your phone.

[image: Banshee]